# finding $\int {(2x + 5)^2}$

Tags: integration, functions

After slowly getting the hang of differentiation I have moved onto integration and I can't seem to understand this one. 
I know the answer is $$\frac{4x^3}{3} + 10x + 25x + C$$

I understand that $$\int {4x^2} dx = \frac{4x^3}{3} $$
And that the $25x$ comes from the $\int 5^2 dx$

I know the integral of a sum of two functions is the sum of the separate integrals. So I had that $\int 2x^2 dx + \int 5^2 dx = \frac{4x^3}{3} + 25x$ but I don't know where the $10x^2$ comes from..

Comment: $(2x +5)^2 \neq  4x^2 + 5^2$

Comment: it's not even equal $\frac{4x^3}{3} + 10x + 25x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: $(2x+5)^2 \neq 2x^2 + 5^2$. Remember: $(2x+5)^2 = (2x+5)(2x+5)$.

Comment: Oh my god I feel like such an idiot, I've been overthinking this.. I blame the lack of sleep to finish off all my work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$(2x+5)^2=4x^2+10x+10x+25=4x^2+20x+25$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int {(2x + 5)^2} = \int {4x^2 + 20x + 25} = \frac{4x^3}{3} + 10x^2 + 25x + C$$

Comment: Nope, re-compute $(2x+5)^2$

Comment: Should be $20x$ instead of $10x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok I did fix it

Answer (score 1):

another easy way to determine this is let w = (2x + 5) so you will have $\frac{dw}{dx} = 2 \rightarrow dx = 1/2 * dw$ so you will get $\frac{1}{2} \int(w^2)$ = $\frac{1}{6}w^3 + C$ = $\frac{1}{6}(2x + 5)^3 + C$

Also if you take the derivative while remembering the chain rule you will get your original integral which is always a good check!